# Picture placement, and properly tagging h1 and h2 elements

Tags: html, css

Ok so I'm just playing around with web development and i'm making my personal site just to get experience. Currently I am having two issues.

1. I have my "About" section I can't seem to be able to move my picture in the center and making the radius 100%. It's really bugging me because it won't work. I already put the CSS border-radius: 100% and Margin: 0 auto; but nothings working. I then tried the Text-align: center; and it didn't work.
2. I have a solid border that extends from the "#section" ID. But I want it not to cover my footer. In the index page it includes the footer which I don't want, but on my other pages like About, and Contact it does not cover the footer like i initially intended it to do. 
   Also on my header I have an H1 and H3 element that goes back to my home page. My problem with it is that when I move the mouse away from the header to the left or right horizontally it still shows that there's a link even though the letters are not there. I want the link to end where the word ends.

Can somebody find out what am I doing wrong and how i can do to avoid it?

I will include my HTML index page, then About page and then my CSS.

Index page where i want to exclude the footer from solid border.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title>Dalexis The Great Critic</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header >
        <a href="index.html" class="headersection">
            <h1>Dalexis Peguero</h1>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html" class="headersection">
            <h3>Designing Websites Since Last Month</h3>
       </a>
        <nav class="navsection">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class="selected">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <a href="About.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </header>
        <div id="section">
            <section >
             <div id="statement">
                <h2>We are so confident in our abilites to satisfy you that we'll give you your money back if you weren't satisfied!</h2>
                       <h4>Get Invoces: We provide the quickest way to get people to buy your shit! </h4>
                       <h4>Make them happy: We'll make sure your customers are all happy! </h4>
             </div>
            <div id="testimonies">
                <h2> Client Testimonies </h2>
                <hr style="width:90%; />
                <p class="paragraph"> <img src="teona.jpg" class="clients"/>He was amazing with services! He did everything right!" </p>
                    <h6>Home Town Loser </h3>
                <hr style="width:90%; />
                <p class="paragraph"> <img src="marvin.jpg" class="clients"/>"As a rapper I enjoyed his services. He made my website look hella dope and I loved it! Will return to him"</p>
                    <h6>MArvelous Marv</h3>
                <hr style="width:90%; />
                <p class="paragraph"> <img src="jon.jpg" class="clients"/>"He was quick and succint! He helped me make my own dispensary website and now all my clients are so satisfied! Thanks Dalexis! !"</p>
                    <h6>Another Home Town Loser </h3>
                <hr style="width:90%; />
                </div>

            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
                <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="IMG/facebook-logo.png" alt="facebook" class="socialicon"></a>
                <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="IMG/twitter-logo.png" alt="twitter" class="socialicon"></a>
                <p>&copy Dalexis Industries </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my about page where i want to center my picture and make the radius 100%.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title>Dalexis The Great Critic</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header >
           <a href="index.html" class="headersection">
            <h1>Dalexis Peguero</h1>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html" class="headersection">
            <h3>Designing Websites Since Last Month</h3>
       </a>
        <nav class="navsection">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <a href="About.html" class="selected">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </header>



             <img src="IMG/dalexis.jpg" alt="my photo" class="about-photo" > 
             <h3>About<h3>
             <p> This is my Web Design website. If you are interested in my services you can either call me or email me. I've been desiging websites for five weeks and my costumers love their sites"</p> 
             <p> If you like to follow me on facebook you can find me at <a href="http://facebook.com/dalexis">Dalexis</a>.
        </div>
        <footer>
                <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="IMG/facebook-logo.png" alt="facebook" class="socialicon"></a>
                <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="IMG/twitter-logo.png" alt="twitter" class="socialicon"></a>
                <p>&copy Dalexis Industries </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 body {
      font-family: abel;
  }

  h1, h3 {
         text-align:center;
   }

 a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #373737;
  }

  ul {
     list-style: none;
   }

   img {
       max-width: 100%;

    }

html {
     color: #373737;
     background-image:url('bkg-blu.jpg');
 }
/******************************
HEADER    
***********************************/


 }

 #nav li  {  display:inline; border-style:groove;  }
 #nav  {text-align:center; }



/******************************
nav    
***********************************/


/******************************
SECTION
***********************************/



 #statement {
            text-align: center;
}


  #testimonies {
               text-align: center;
   }
 section h2 {
         margin: 0 20px;
         padding: 0px 60px;
  }

  #section {
           border-style:solid;
           border-width: 1px;
           width: 90%;
           height: 100%;
           padding: 5px 5px;
           margin:15px 5px 15px 100px;       
   }

   section div p img {
              font-style:italic;
              color: blue;
    }


.clients {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
} 
/******************************
footer
***********************************/

.socialicon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
} 

 footer img {

        margin: 0;
        color: fff;
        clear: both;

  }


  .selected, a:hover {
            color: grey;
   }

   /******************************
   PAGE:  ABOUT 
   /***************************/

   .about-photo {
                width: 250px;
                height: 200px;
                display: block;
                display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  max-width: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;

    }
```

Comment: A link to view the problem would be helpful.

Comment: to me it's looks like what you are expexting : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/0g0zu7fn/ (round image

Comment: yes that's exactly what i am thinking !! but somehow i cant get it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for question 1.

Change this

```
<img src="IMG/dalexis.jpg" alt="my photo">
```

To this

```
<div class="about-photo"><img src="IMG/dalexis.jpg" alt="my photo"></div>
```

CSS

```
.about-photo {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.about-photo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```